# Deleting a cell from table and adding images to the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 questions;

1.) i have added a button to a cell, and upon clicking that button i need to delete that cell (i don't want to use the edit feature of the cell to do this). I don't think i should show you the code how i added the button to the cell (i think it has nothing to do with this). Can someone help me delete the cell from the table. My button even is as follows;

```
-(void)deleteCellFromTable:(id)sender{

}
```

2.) How do i add Images or photots in the simulator ?

Comment: Dragging a photo onto the simulator window creates a blue box around he screen to accept the file. Does it not?

Comment: in the second question, you want add images in your app or you want to save images in you simulator gallery?

Answer (score 1):

1. One way I can think of is to delete the data from the array you are loading into the TableView and reloading the tableview's data to achieve this.
2. you open the simulator and drag and drop images into it. it will be added automatically

Answer (score 0):

1. You will want to call [`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a) on your tableview and pass an array with the row's index as well as the animation you want to occur.
2. I assume you mean selecting an image from the UIImagePickerController? You can save an image from Safari and it will be saved to your media library (viewable from Photos.app). If you have a file on disk that you want to add you can drag and drop it to the simulator and the simulator will open the image in Safari, you can then save it from there as normal (hold down on the image till the option comes up)

Comment: I think its possible to select an image from the library and use in the simulator. I did it a while ago but cant remember how exactly. if you want I can find the code

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi I tried out what you said by dragging/dropping it into the simulator and it will open the image in Safari, very cool! You can then save that image off to your media library, I assume these would then be available to select from `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: yup they are available in the photo library so as long as you use UIImagePickerController you will be able to select the image from there

Answer (score 0):

One siplese way is:

Just add an image to the view already existed in cell instead of data.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imagenamed:urImage];
```

Comment: I agree with Your answer. You are give just simply. Akkada adigindi emiti nuvvu cheppindi emit ra

Comment: Hi wat language u are talking to me..
I was unable to undersatand... ur language.. plese let me know in english @kareen

Comment: Mundu spelling mistakes lekunda rayadam nerchuko not kareen it is kareem